# Can't import csv file on to collab?

Tags: python, csv, compiler-errors, path, file-not-found

I'm fair new to python and have been trying to csv file onto a google collab notebook. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Have already tried using '/' and  instead however they also are not working.

```
import pandas as pd
testData = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\ml\training.csv')
```

I am getting multiple errors:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d77976d861ee> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 testData = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\ml\training.csv')
      3 
      4 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\User\Documents\ml\training.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\ml\\training.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab cannot read files from your local device, it's running on a server on the cloud, and doesn't have access to your local filesystem.  You need to upload your files.  There are many ways to accomplish this, look up one that suits your needs best.

An example that prompts you for file upload and then you can read it into your notebook.

```
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()


df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['filename.csv']))
```